# Inline Eval if statement returning constant

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, eval

I have an if statement currently written (wrongly) as:

```
<%# Eval("AccumHolidays").ToString() != "" ? Eval("AccumHolidays").ToString() : Eval("Holidays").ToString() != "" ? Eval("Holidays").ToString() : %> 0 <% %>
```

This works until I want to output the 0 in the final else. Looking for something like:

```
if(Eval("AccumHolidays").ToString() != "")
    Eval("AccumHolidays").ToString();
else
    if(Eval("Holidays").ToString() != "")
        Eval("Holidays").ToString();
    else
        Response.Write("0");
```

I might have the arguments the wrong way around, but what would be the correct statement to put in the aspx page?

Comment: Maybe you just need `: "0"` at the end

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple, thought I'd tried every possible combination!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%# Eval("AccumHolidays").ToString() != "" ? 
Eval("AccumHolidays").ToString() : Eval("Holidays").ToString() != "" ? 
Eval("Holidays").ToString() : "0"%>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm suggesting an alternative approach, feel free to ignore it if you don't like it. Why not create a new property in your data source like this

```
public string HolidaysText
{
    get
    {
        if (AccumHolidays.ToString() != "")
            return AccumHolidays.ToString();
        if (Holidays.ToString() != "")
            return Holidays.ToString();
        return "0";
    }
}
```

Then you can have a simple Eval statement in your page

```
<%# Eval("HolidaysText") %>
```

Comment: This is a good solution but I went with the other one just because it was simplest.